# How can I Export transparency and text well when using qgis2web in QGIS 3.8?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

[image: No.1]
[image: No.2]
[image]

Hi, I am an amateur who is making a historical map.
As you can see in the picture, I have a problem using qgis2web.

The first picture is a normal scene output from QGIS version 3.8.

The second picture was taken from qgis2web with a Mapbox. Transparency is nice, but the text in the labels is terrible.

The third picture was taken from qgis2web with openlayers. Transparency, text in labels, it's all a mess.

I tested [this site](http://eastmaps.com/2019/09/10/%ED%85%8C%EC%8A%A4%ED%8A%B8/) a year ago, but it was fine at the time. What should I do ? It's too hard...

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/buub8x/qgis2web_not_preserving_transparency_of_layers/?sort=new

it's same problem I think so...

Answer (score 3):

I finally got the answer!

I set the opacity of the color of the layer.
But the opacity of the layer rendering was 100%.
When I lowered the opacity of layer rendering, not a single symbol, the qgis2web worked successfully.

People who are struggling with this, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Open the HTML file in notepad and scroll down the code until you get to the layer you want the transparency to change. it should look something like:

function style_20YearFlood_2_0() {

```
        return {
            pane: 'pane_20YearFlood_2',
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'rgba(35,35,35,1.0)',
            dashArray: '',
            lineCap: 'butt',
            lineJoin: 'miter',
            weight: 1.0, 
            fill: true,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            fillColor: 'rgba(255,158,23,1.0)',
            interactive: false,
```

20 year flood in my case was the layer I wanted to be partly transparent.Then just change the "fillOpacity:" to whatever you want. I chose 50% so it now looks like:

function style_20YearFlood_2_0() {

```
        return {
            pane: 'pane_20YearFlood_2',
            opacity: 0.5,
            color: 'rgba(35,35,35,1.0)',
            dashArray: '',
            lineCap: 'butt',
            lineJoin: 'miter',
            weight: 1.0, 
            fill: true,
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            fillColor: 'rgba(255,158,23,1.0)',
            interactive: false,
```

Save the file, and then open the html in your browser. It should now be transparent to whatever % you indicated.

Hope this helps!

Ian